# Why request() helper return empty array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to use request information at report() function in Error Handler, but can't get it.

```php
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    $request = request();
    // -> empty array
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Why request() helper return empty array?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `request()->all()` instead?

Comment: What information do you like to know about in the request?

Comment: `request()->all()` return empty array too. @InOre

Comment: Information I need most is the request url. @MisaGH

Comment: You can use `url()->current()` or `url()->full()`

Comment: Thanks, nice methods. If you post answer, I will choose the best answer. @MisaGH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use url helpers:

```
url()->current();
```

or

```
url()->full();
```